Why is using ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES} not modern CMake?
Given this change suggestion:
-  PUBLIC ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}
+  PUBLIC OpenSSL::SSL OpenSSL::Crypto

Why is using OpenSSL::SSL OpenSSL::Crypto considered modern CMake over using the OPENSSL_LIBRARIES variable?
According to FindOpenSSL docs the OPENSSL_LIBRARIES variable is not deprecated, but it seems that CMake experts agree that it is not modern CMake.
I see in unclejimbo's guide:

"And that’s it, modern CMake could handle target dependencies transitively, which means that you could forget about the messy variables and every property needed to use libmodern is handled correctly."

But I'm struggling to understand why we don't use variables any more. Is it just because they look messy?

We don't use variables because we have no idea which variables are set, and unset variables expand to nothing.
Is it OPENSSL_LIBRARIES or OpenSSL_LIBRARIES or OPENSSL_LIB or OPENSSL_LIBS or ...? Does there exist or not some OPENSSL_CFLAGS or OPENSSL_LDFLAGS or OPENSSL_FLAGS or OPENSSL_CPPFLAGS or OPENSSL_FFLAGS that you have to use? In case of big packages like openssl it is well documented, but users made packages that can and do set any kind of variables and follow no convetion. There actually was no convetion on variable names in packages some time ago and every package was different.
Missing targets cause an error, and stuff with :: has to be a target, and also one target has everything - language specific flags, ldflags, libraries, include paths, library paths - in one name. And if you make a typo, you get an error.

Got it, so using variables is not strict, whereas using targets is strict and fails faster. Right?

The other (the most important IMHO) thing with targets vs variables -- you just need to call only target_link_libraries(…) to get everything work vs extra calls to target_include_directories(…), target_compile_definitions(…), target_link_directories(…), and possibly other friends feeding them with a bunch of variables (sometimes named differently depending on a finder module).
And yes, variables are fragile! There are plenty of ways to make the build process broken by messing with variables.
